# How to combine two multi-dimensional arrays based on key value pairs without nested foreach loop?

Tags: php, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array, foreach

I have 2 arrays,`$fileArr` and `$noteArr`.

`$fileArr` is a list a files. A file can be linked to more than one story. So within this `$fileArr`, you are seeing all files per story that I need to list out.  Notice that CAR.jpg (`[processId]=>111`), is linked to both `[storyId]=>1` and `[storyId]=>2`. So CAR.jpg will be listed twice.

I want to take all notes from `$noteArr`, and place them into `$fileArr` by matching `[processId`]. So each instance of CAR.jpg will have 2 notes, whereas TRUCK.jpg won't have any.

**My current $fileArr**

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [fileName] => CAR.jpg
        [processId] => 111
        [storyId] => 1
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [fileName] => CAR.jpg
        [processId] => 111
        [storyId] => 2
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [fileName] => TRUCK.jpg
        [processId] => 222
        [storyId] => 3
    )
)
```

**My current $noteArr**

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [noteId] => 50
        [note] => this is a note
        [processId] => 111
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [noteId] => 51
        [note] => and this is also a note
        [processId] => 111
    )

)
```

**My intended new array with notes placed under the file by matching processId**

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [fileName] => CAR.jpg
        [processId] => 111
        [storyId] => 1
        [notes] => Array
              (
                    [50] => Array
                          (
                                [noteId] => 50
                                [note] => this is a note
                                [processId] => 111
                          )
                    [51] => Array
                          (
                                [noteId] => 51
                                [note] => and this is also a note
                                [processId] => 111
                          )
              )
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [fileName] => CAR.jpg
        [processId] => 111
        [storyId] => 2
        [notes] => Array
              (
                    [50] => Array
                          (
                                [noteId] => 50
                                [note] => this is a note
                                [processId] => 111
                          )
                    [51] => Array
                          (
                                [noteId] => 51
                                [note] => and this is also a note
                                [processId] => 111
                          )
              )
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [fileName] => TRUCK.jpg
        [processId] => 222
        [storyId] => 3
    )
)
```

I can accomplish this through the code I've written below, but do not want to use a loop within a loop. Is there another way that I can achieve this?

**My current code (loop within loop)**

```
$newArr = array();

$i = 0;
foreach($fileArr as $file){
    $newArr[$i] = $file;

    if(count($noteArr)>0){
        foreach($noteArr as $note){
            if($file['processId']==$note['processId']){
                $newArr[$i]['notes'][$note['id']] = $note;
            }
        }
    }
    $i++;
}
```

Comment: Question, why don't you want to use nested loops?

Comment: Hi @Difster, I was taught that nested loops should be avoided when necessary due to complexity and the chance of getting stuck in a never ending loop. I know sometimes they are needed, but if there is an instance where I can use another solution I usually go that route. Do you see this as a case where it is necessary?

Comment: @jmchauv You shouldn't get stuck in a never ending loop with a foreach as it just iterates from the first to the last element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to remove the nested loop to reduce time of execution, you can do it by two passes

```
// save items of noteArr for each processId
$temp = [];
foreach($noteArr as $k => $note) {
   $temp[$note['processId']][] = $note;
}

// and add saved sub-arrays to the source one
$newArr = [];
$i = 0;
foreach($fileArr as $file){
    $newArr[$i] = $file;
    if(isset($temp[$file['processId']])) 
         $newArr[$i]['notes'] = $temp[$file['processId'];
    $i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Without nested loops, you can create a function and pass by reference:

```
function addNote(array &$array, array $notes)
{
    $array['notes'] = [];
    foreach ($notes as $note)
    {
        if ($note['processId'] == $array['processId']) {
            $array['notes'][] = $note;
        }
    }
    return $array;
}

foreach ($fileArr as &$file) {
    addNote($file, $notes);
}

var_dump($fileArr);
```

See it working here https://3v4l.org/u37UL

Comment: Surely this is just a nested loop, but with 1 loop inside a function?!

Comment: Yeah, this is still a nested loop, just extracted into another method.

Answer (score 0):

Hi i do a quick look how I would solve your problem. Unfortunately its ended up in a nested loop, but i don't need to loop any item ( in your solution, you loop all notes for every file)  twice.

```
function sortProcessId($a, $b)
{
    return $a['processId'] <=> $b['processId'];
}

$newArr = [];

usort($fileArr, 'sortProcessId');
usort($noteArr, 'sortProcessId');
rsort($noteArr);
$currentProcessId = 0;
$currentNote = array_pop($noteArr);
$newArr = [];
foreach ($fileArr as $key => $file){
    $newArr[$key] = $file;
    if ($currentProcessId === $file['processId']) {
        $newArr[$key]['notes'] = [ $newArr[--$key]['notes']];
        continue;
    }
    $newArr[$key]['notes'] = [];
    $currentProcessId = $file['processId'];
    while ($file['processId'] == $currentNote['processId']) {
        $newArr[$key]['notes'][$currentNote['noteId']] = $currentNote;
        $currentNote = array_pop($noteArr);
    }
}
var_dump($newArr);
```

Additional Notes:
 I used rsort to use array_pop which should be faster than array_shift

Answer (score 0):

You can use a bunch of the array functions in PHP.

```
array_walk($fileArr, function(&$item) use ($noteArr) {
  $processId = $item['processId'];
  $foundNotes = array_filter($noteArr, function($note) use ($processId) {
    return $note['processId'] === $processId;
  });

  if (!empty($foundNotes)) {
    $item['notes'] = $foundNotes;
  }
});
```

This will alter your `$fileArr` to become what I believe you want.

*FWIW* I don't think the nested loop is a bad way of doing it.  while this code solves the problem in the way you ask, I think it's harder to understand.